# how to get title of youtube video using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new in using Python and BeautifulSoup. I want to get title and description of a video.

I am getting a description using this code:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 x='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjG5ZwuY0Rc'
 source = requests.get(x).text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
 for p in soup.find_all('p', id='eow-description'):
     print(p.get_text('\n'))
```

How can I get title of the video?

Answer (score 1):

To fetch any desired text from an html page:

1. Get the tag name by inspecting element in the browser(right click on browser and click inspect for chrome) if it is not known already.
2. Get the id of the desired tag.

Once you have details of 1 & 2, using `get_text` it is easy to get the details of that tag.

```
for title in soup.find_all('span', id="eow-title"):
    print(title.get_text('\n'))
```